# How to detect whether Google Chrome is blocking Flash from playing

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome

In Google Chrome there is an option to turn of running any browser plugin (like Flash, Java etc) from running automatically. If you set the preference as click to play, the user will have to click on the Flash container to run the Flash app.

My question is how to detect (in JavaScript) whether Google Chrome has blocked Flash from playing, so that I can display a message to the user.

Comment: well.. m not exactly sure if it ll work or not. but you can try this. add an onload eventlistener to your object tag, so after this is loaded you can call any method in flash through your javascript. If its restricted you should get a NP. just guessing haven't tried it yet..

Comment: Calling a method if Flash is disabled is causing Flash to crash.

Comment: are you getting load complete event from object tag if flash is disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the flash object call an external interface function like "flashReady".
In javascript, if the page has loaded and after a timeout of a few seconds, if flashReady has not been called, it is likely blocked (or still loading, but you can get around that by making the swf call the function during the beginning of loading).